# How to check if Caffe is using my GPU?

Tags: caffe

Same as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152674/how-to-check-if-pytorch-is-using-the-gpu) but for caffe. I want a command I can put in my python script to check if gpu is utilized.

I have checked nvidia-smi while my model is running and I see that python is recognized as a process but Usage is N/A.

I also tried running the caffe.set_mode_cpu() command thinking that the times would be very different but the times with the command and without where the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest the use of [GPUSTAT](https://github.com/wookayin/gpustat). You can query the GPU and check if your process is in the list returned by the command.
It is simple, not too elegant but it works.