# any script to test the installation of Pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I have installed the pytorch, and would like to check are there any script to test whether the installation is correct, e.g., whether it can enable CUDA or not, etc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if pytorch is using the GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152674/how-to-check-if-pytorch-is-using-the-gpu)

Answer (score 5):

Coming to your 1st question,
In your python script....
just add

```
import torch
```

if this gives "**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'**",
then your pytorch installation is not complete

And your 2nd question to check if your pytorch is using cuda,use this

```
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

this will return **True** if your pytorch is using cuda

Comment: This alone will not verify that pytorch will work. See [this issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/31285)

Comment: there are some issues with TITAN series

Comment: Given the comments on [the issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/31285), and my own personal case, it seems that for any GPU that has `sm_86` capabilities, this script will run successfully, but will end up failing when you try to run real code/do ML training. [Bai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71988947/5049813), which includes more tests of the true functionality, will fail if attempted on these sorts of GPUs.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`collect_env.py`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/pytorch/master/torch/utils/collect_env.py) script provided in the PyTorch [utils](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/tree/master/torch/utils) folder.

Its output is as follows:

```
Collecting environment information...
PyTorch version: 1.2.0
Is debug build: No
CUDA used to build PyTorch: 10.0.130

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
GCC version: (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
CMake version: version 3.14.6

Python version: 3.7
Is CUDA available: Yes
CUDA runtime version: Could not collect
GPU models and configuration: GPU 0: GeForce RTX 2080
Nvidia driver version: 410.48
cuDNN version: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.7.4.1

Versions of relevant libraries:
[pip] numpy==1.16.4
[pip] torch==1.2.0
[pip] torchsample==0.1.3
[pip] torchsummary==1.5.1
[pip] torchvision==0.4.0a0+6b959ee
[conda] blas                      1.0                         mkl  
[conda] mkl                       2019.4                      243  
[conda] mkl-service               2.0.2            py37h7b6447c_0  
[conda] mkl_fft                   1.0.14           py37ha843d7b_0  
[conda] mkl_random                1.0.2            py37hd81dba3_0  
[conda] pytorch                   1.2.0           py3.7_cuda10.0.130_cudnn7.6.2_0    pytorch
[conda] torchsample               0.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
[conda] torchsummary              1.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
[conda] torchvision               0.4.0                py37_cu100    pytorch
```

Answer (score 3):

If you installed it from [here](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#installing-on-linux) you are doing fine.

[image]

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152674/how-to-check-if-pytorch-is-using-the-gpu):

```
import torch
dev = torch.device("cuda") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")
print(dev)
```

If you have your GPU installed correctly you should have `nvidia-smi`.
(On Windows it should be inside `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use my code. This repo implements a set of PyTorch environment checker and cuda-based operators, which helps you verify whether your GPU-based PyTorch is installed properly.

https://github.com/BAI-Yeqi/PyTorch-Verification