# GCP DL Image: Base m36 (with CUDA 10.0). How to enable GPU in PyTorch?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, pytorch, fast-ai

I am trying to run DL PyTorch jobs on a GCP box. Steps I take:

- Create a VM with m36 deep learning image and K80 attached. There is a question re CUDA 10 driver installation at first login, I choose 'y' and the driver gets set up.
- install pyenv
- `pyenv install 3.7.5`
- `pyenv virtualenv 3.7.5 myenv`
- `pyenv activate myenv`
- `pip install fastai`
- Start python console and run:

Code:

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

It returns `False`. What am I supposed to do to enable GPU in PyTorch?

Comment: Google also give free GPU in [Google Colab](http://colab.research.google.com/) you can try it at  [link](http://colab.research.google.com/) http://colab.research.google.com/  

You need google acocunt to run Python Programs online with it. If you don't know how to use this Google Colab you can follow this tutorial: colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb 
you have to enable gpu on setting Rutime > Change Runtime type

Comment: Thanks but colab is not what I am looking for.

Comment: checkout this answer it might help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/48152674/7001213