# Pytorch cuda get_device_name and current_device() hang and are killed?

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I've just installed a new GPU (RTX 2070) in my machine alongside the old GPU. I wanted to see if PyTorch picked up it, so following the instructions here: [How to check if pytorch is using the GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152674/how-to-check-if-pytorch-is-using-the-gpu), I ran the following commands (Python3.6.9, Linux Mint Tricia 19.3)

```
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
True
>>> torch.cuda.current_device()
Killed
>>> torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)
Killed
```

Both of the two Killed processes took some time and one of them froze the machine for half a minute or so. Does anyone have any experience with this? Are there some setup steps I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you would like to list the available cuda devices. This can be done via `nvidia-smi` (not a PyTorch function), and both your old GPU and the RTX 2070 should show up, as devices `0` and `1`. In PyTorch, if you want to pass data to one specific device, you can do `device = torch.device("cuda:0")` for GPU 0 and `device = torch.device("cuda:1")` for GPU 1. While running, you can do `nvidia-smi` to check the memory usage & running processes for each GPU.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone seeing this down the line, whilst I had the nvidia driver set up I needed to get a couple of other things set up, such as CUDA and the CuDNN toolbox. The best article I found on the subject was https://hackernoon.com/up-and-running-with-ubuntu-nvidia-cuda-cudnn-tensorflow-and-pytorch-a54ec2ec907d.