# How to Print os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

My machine has three GPUs with indexes `0, 1, and 2.` To assign my program to a specific GPU, I used the lines below:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1"
```

How can I print the GPU index on which my program is executing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I list all currently available GPUs with pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64776822/how-do-i-list-all-currently-available-gpus-with-pytorch)

Comment: No, I just want to print my set "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES".

Comment: Have you tried `torch.cuda.current_device()`?

Comment: @Hamzah thanks for the comment. It gives index "0" GPU even when I execute os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1" before execution `torch.cuda.current_device()`.

Comment: Have you tried also this: `device = torch.device("cuda:1")` and then `torch.cuda.current_device()`?

Comment: Still, it's gives "0".

Comment: I might misunderstand something, but on my computer this `print(os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"])` prints the number, you set before.