# How to build YOLACT++ using Docker?

Tags: docker, pytorch, dockerfile, amazon-sagemaker

I have to build yolact++ in docker enviromment (i'm using sagemaker notebook). Like this

```
ARG PYTORCH="1.3"
ARG CUDA="10.1"
ARG CUDNN="7"
 
FROM pytorch/pytorch:${PYTORCH}-cuda${CUDA}-cudnn${CUDNN}-devel
```

And i want to run this

```
COPY yolact/external/DCNv2/setup.py /opt/ml/code/external/DCNv2/setup.py
RUN cd /opt/ml/code/external/DCNv2 && \
python setup.py build develop
```

But i got this error :

```
No CUDA runtime is found, using CUDA_HOME='/usr/local/cuda'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 64, in <module>
ext_modules=get_extensions(),
File "setup.py", line 41, in get_extensions
raise NotImplementedError('Cuda is not available')
NotImplementedError: Cuda is not available
```

But the enviromment supports CUDA. Anyone have an idea where is the problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: The error message indicate CUDA is not considered installed by the python compiler. Did you try to check the presence (and the path) of the CUDA installation ?

Comment: I cheched if cuda is available it returns False, but  when i check the version of cuda is returns me 10.1,  i set CUDA_PATH to CUDA_HOME="/usr/local/cuda-10.1".

Comment: Ok so if it still says `using CUDA_HOME='/usr/local/cuda'` then your setting of `CUDA_HOME` does not work.

Comment: And How i can solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLUTION :

i edit the /etc/docker/daemon.json with content:

```
{
"runtimes": {
    "nvidia": {
        "path": "/usr/bin/nvidia-container-runtime",
        "runtimeArgs": []
     } 
},
"default-runtime": "nvidia" 
}
```

Then i Restart docker daemon:

```
sudo system restart docker
```

it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting your CUDA_HOME variable in your dockerfile like this :

```
ARG PYTORCH="1.3"
ARG CUDA="10.1"
ARG CUDNN="7"

FROM pytorch/pytorch:${PYTORCH}-cuda${CUDA}-cudnn${CUDNN}-devel
ARG CUDA_HOME="/usr/local/cuda-10.1"
```

...and see if the python compiler sees it then.

Comment: it still says : No CUDA runtime is found, using CUDA_HOME='/usr/local/cuda-10.1'

Comment: So it's not a problem with the path. You said `cuda.is_available()` returns false... then you have to figure out why. Maybe you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152674/how-to-check-if-pytorch-is-using-the-gpu