# Why isn't my PyTorch LinearRegression code using GPU?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, gpu, linear-regression

I'm trying to train a simple linear regression model with Pytorch and CUDA. PyTorch can detect CUDA, and there is GPU memory consumption. However, GPU is never used in my code.
This is my code

```
class linearRegression(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inputSize, outputSize):
        super(linearRegression, self).__init__()
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(inputSize, outputSize)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.linear(x)
        return out

def linear_demo():
    # create dummy data for training
    n_data = 1000000
    x_values = n_data*np.random.normal(size=n_data)
    x_train = np.array(x_values, dtype=np.float64)
    x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 1)

    y_values = [2*i + 1 + (np.random.rand(1)-0.5)*5 for i in x_values]
    y_train = np.array(y_values, dtype=np.float64)
    y_train = y_train.reshape(-1, 1)
    x_train /= np.abs(x_train).max()
    y_train /= np.abs(y_train).max()
    print(x_train.shape)
    print(y_train.shape)

    inputDim = 1        # takes variable 'x'
    outputDim = 1       # takes variable 'y'
    learningRate = 1e-2
    epochs = 80
    batch_size = 128*8
    batch_size = n_data

    model = linearRegression(inputDim, outputDim).to(torch.float64)
    ##### For GPU #######
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        model.cuda()
    criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='mean').cuda()
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learningRate)
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        permutation = torch.randperm(n_data)
        idx = permutation[:batch_size]
        # Converting inputs and labels to Variable
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            inputs = Variable(torch.from_numpy(x_train[idx]).cuda())
            labels = Variable(torch.from_numpy(y_train[idx]).cuda())
        else:
            inputs = Variable(torch.from_numpy(x_train[idx]))
            labels = Variable(torch.from_numpy(y_train[idx]))
        # Clear gradient buffers because we don't want any gradient from the previous epoch to carry forward, don't want to accumulate gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # get output from the model, given the inputs
        outputs = model(inputs)

        # get loss for the predicted output
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        if loss.item() > 1:
            print(loss)
        # get gradients w.r.t to parameters
        loss.backward()

        # update parameters
        optimizer.step()

        if (epoch % 10 == 0):
            print('epoch {}, loss {}'.format(epoch, loss.item()))
    return
```

[This is a screenshot of GPU usage.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqnMT.png) Apparently, GPU is not used in computing. [GPU can be detected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zls85.png)

If the computational burden is too low for GPU to display usage, I tried increasing `n_data` to `1e8`, but the GPU usage is still 0%. How can I use GPU computing in this situation? If it's really due to low computational burden, is there any simple way to clearly show that GPU is working?

------update------

1. I tried top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152674/how-do-i-check-if-pytorch-is-using-the-gpu?rq=2), and the terminal returns the expected info. So I believe the installation is correct.
   [screenshot for GPU info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEMeM.png)
2. I also tried device declaration like `inputs.to('cuda')`, `inputs.to(torch.device('cuda'))`, `inputs.cuda()`. They turn out to be [equivalent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyoD5.png).

Comment: You should be moving the model and the inputs to gpu by using `.to(torch.device('cuda'))`

Comment: @null I tried it w/ `model.to(torch.device('cuda'))`, `torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='mean').to(torch.device('cuda'))`,  `inputs = Variable(torch.from_numpy(x_train[idx]).to(torch.device('cuda')))`, and set `n_data=1e7` running in 1 min, but it still has 0 GPU usage.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are there any cases where it does show GPU usage in `pytorch` for you on that machine? Or is this problem exclusive to when you try to use your custom class?

Comment: @BrockBrown I'm new to PyTorch and CUDA. I don't have a case where it shows GPU usage... I actually got the code from [this website](https://towardsdatascience.com/linear-regression-with-pytorch-eb6dedead817). The original code shows no GPU usage on my machine either.

Comment: First you need to declare a device:
```device=torch.device("cuda") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")```
For any model and inputs, you then need to transfer them to that target device
```
device = torch.device("cuda")
x = x.to(device)
model = model.to(device)
```