gpu compatibility check in old laptop while using polars
How to check if the GPU in my old laptop is compatible with the GPU acceleration libraries in Polars?
How to use Polars with GPU in Windows Laptop?
I am just getting starting with Polars. Just thought of leveraging my age old GPU. Any useful resources or pointers will be much appreciated...
My Processor is: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3610QM CPU @ 2.30GHz   2.30 GHz
My GPU is : NVIDIA GeForce GTX 670M
CPU

GPU


Have you looked at this yet ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152674/how-do-i-check-if-pytorch-is-using-the-gpu?rq=2

This question is similar to: How do I check if PyTorch is using the GPU?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf is the library. The polars stuff is "open beta" and has very little (no?) docs though.

@easleyfixed
well, pytorch is bit more advanced for me at the moment. just looking for ways to play around with mere polars leveraging my laptop's gpu...

@jqurious thanks a lot for the link. I now understood that its a work in progress between Polars and NVIDIA engineers through the link.
https://pola.rs/posts/polars-on-gpu/

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/commit/a53bf03 just added docs with some more information.

https://pola.rs/posts/gpu-engine-release/

Polars leverages the power of NVIDIA RAPIDS CUDA libraries for GPU acceleration, significantly boosting performance for machine learning and big data tasks. While the Polars-RAPIDS integration is still evolving, the following information will be valuable for anyone looking to harness the speed of GPUs with NVIDIA RAPIDS.
To begin your journey with RAPIDS, your machine should ideally have GPUs with a compute capability of at least 7.0. Refer the below links to verify the compute compatibility of your GPU
References:

Accelerating Polars DataFrames
https://rapids.ai/
Prerequisites for Getting Started with RAPIDS
Compute Capability for various NVIDIA GPUs

